# Play MP3 on startup

Tags: pi-zero-w, phat-dac

Is there an easy way to play an MP3 song automatically, and/or loop/or have it play through a series of songs in a folder? I am trying to do this on a Zero and am stuck. I have a Phat Dac connected to it that works brilliantly with lineout speakers.

Basically, I just want to turn on and have white noise machine  without doing anything else.

It will play a wav file in the terminal but not loop or go through a folder.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use a shell script, that triggers your favorite mp3 wav player via command line.., you can customize a script file to do all sorts of nifty commands like cycle through all tracks.. and have that script load up in an rc.local file to trigger at startup.

Lots of ways you can do this,
I'm sure you might be able to load a gui based player via command line with a playlist file of tracks or one track, and pass it parameters like volume, file, repeat all etc

You will need to find a good player to suit your needs and do a little research on scripting if you go that route.

I find the nifty Node-Red flowchart based programming IDE can open a wide world of awesome possibilities with interactive fun stuff, and makes programming things like that a little simpler, but might be Overkill for a simple scripts task.

Comment: Peoples looking for an awesome command line player, try out MOC https://www.fossmint.com/moc-music-player-for-linux-console/ !

Answer (score 1):

To execute a command at system startup, without the need to login, so you don't need a screen at all, edit the file `/etc/rc.local`.

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Paste any command there, and make sure the file end with `exit 0`.

Also make sure to use the **full path** to link your audio file.

```
#!/bin/sh -e   
aplay /home/pi/Music/noise.wav
exit 0
```

`aplay` is a command line player that should be installed by default.

Then give execution rights, so the file get executed at system startup:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

To specifically generate white/pink noise, add audio effects and many more,  other advanced tools can do that, like `ffmpeg` or `sox`.

Comment: Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it.

Comment: This is how unix systems works,get over it.

Comment: [This is a somewhat contentious issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/471871/25985), which, based on the trajectory of community attitudes toward `systemd` over the past decade, means that the trend is toward abandoning non-legacy use of `/etc/rc.local`, something readers should be aware of.  The Pi Foundation [still condones it](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md), although IMO they tend to be a bit behind the ball, linux wise....

Comment: As for it being *"how unix systems works"*, that's technically false: It's not specified by the UNIX or POSIX standards, and historically is a [BSD convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init#Research_Unix-style/BSD-style) which was inserted into SysV.

Comment: I believe you, but you must now provide a concise answer about the usage of `systemd` headless! Tx!

Comment: @NVRM I have done it

Comment: I had upvoted, thanks, hacking around.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a **systemd** unit file to run a program at startup. Try this simple Unit to start with your project. If it runs on bootup you can improve it step by step.

Create a new service with

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --force --full edit my-startup-song.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save them and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=Play song at startup
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/aplay /full/path/to/noise.wav

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Enable the new service with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --now enable my-startup-song.service
```

Instead of the example with **aplay** use the player of your choice, maybe **mpg123**.